# How to listFiles() from mapped network drive from a java program running in cygwin?

Tags: java, cygwin, directory, network-drive

I´m trying to list all files from a folder located in a mapped network drive. The java program is running in cygwin (since I need to run linux-like commands from java).

The problem is when I try to open the directory /cygdrive/mappedDrive/myFolder File.exists() returns false.

Any ideas of how to make this work?

Thanks

Comment: And does myFolder exists? I mean: are you able to access your folder through the path you are indicating to Java?

Comment: Yes, I can access it from cygwin if I type "dir /cygdrive/mappedDrive/myFolder".

Answer (score 0):

When you execute Java from Cygwin, Java is just executed as separate process with no knowledge of cygwin or its alternative directory structure.
That only exists for the cygwin shell and (all other) programs that are compiled and linked with cygwin compiler/libraries.

To have /cygdrive paths work in Java you'd have to recompile Java using Cygwin. There might be a Java interpretor for Cygwin, but I don't know how or if that works.